# How can show a VAT column in the woocommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to show a Vat column in the woocommerce cart

currently in my child theme cart.php i can see this

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="product-price" ><?php _e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <th class="product-quantity"><?php _e( 'Qty', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
        <th class="product-subtotal"><?php _e( 'Total', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

i know how to put a column in there
but i think the line that needs focusing on is

```
 <td class="product-subtotal">
                    <?php
                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', WC()->cart->get_product_subtotal( $_product, $cart_item['quantity'] ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
                    ?>
                </td>
```

so every product in the order will display tax or no tax if a zero rate

Comment: Prices entered with tax - yes, Caculate taxes on shop address, display prices including tax

Comment: thought really i should enter price as exluding VAT